# How to ensure that chat_id exists?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I wrote a piece of code which sends messages to a Telegram bot. In order to do so, I use the `chat_id` of the last conversation retrieved via the [`getUpdates` method](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates).

```
id = requests.get(f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/getUpdates").json()['result'][-1]['message']['chat']['id']
```

My understanding is that the a conversation exists if someone started one with the bot via `/start`.

**How can I initiate, from my code, a conversation to make sure a `chat_id` is available?** (= that there is a conversion I can query).

I am also sure that the conversations, should they exist, are not kept indefinitely (this is another reason why requesting an update can yield empty results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *My understanding is that the a conversation exists if someone started one with the bot via /start.*

Yes, conversation is always [initiated by a user](https://core.telegram.org/bots#4-how-are-bots-different-from-humans):

> Bots can't initiate conversations with users. A user must either add them to a group or send them a message first. People can use telegram.me/ links or username search to find your bot.

Note that `/start` is not the only option here.

If you try to send a message for user, who didn't start conversation with bot, you will receive something like this: `{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: chat not found"}`.

---

> *How can I initiate, from my code, a conversation to make sure a chat_id is available? (= that there is a conversion I can query).*

Normally, you shouldn't worry about that. Bot does not query specific user actions/requests with `getUpdates`, it queries all interactions from all users and then decides what to do according to internal logic you provide.

You may want to store information about users and/or their requests in a database every time you receive an `Update` from particular user in `getUpdates`.

Based on that, bot can make a decision to send for example, a message to him.

---

> *I am also sure that the conversations, should they exist, are not kept indefinitely (this is another reason why requesting an update can yield empty results)*

Yes, [docs clearly state](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates) that

> Incoming updates are stored on the server until the bot receives them either way, but they will not be kept longer than **24 hours**.

An `Update` on a Telegram servers is an entity with a short life period.

If you haven't saved information about existing users, or lost a database, **there's no way to retrieve that data from telegram servers.**

---

P.S.: as a side note, I'd suggest using long polling, as [Telegram Bot API is designed](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates) to be used with [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) if you're using `getUpdates`. The most important thing is the `timeout` request parameter of `getUpdates` method:

> (timeout is) Timeout in seconds for long polling. **Defaults to 0**, i.e. usual short polling. Should be positive, **short polling should be used for testing purposes only**.

As written in question, you're using short polling.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, after which I believe that I am missing something. I intend to use Telegram as a message hub where an application of mine would send a message (to the bot i created, I believe?) which I would then receive on my devices because i initiated a chat with that bot from each device. In that case the bot acts as a "hub", without any interaction - just as a mean to share a "conversation" (monologue from my app, actually).

Comment: (cont'd) There would be no more interaction with the bot from my devices, beyond the initial `/start` to get engaged with him. I am not sure Telegram is actually intended for such activity, on a second thought (as opposed to, say, Pushbullet)

Comment: Bot api can be used for many purposes, so it may be a good idea. And if you have static list of you devices you can just harcode their id's in the bot.

Comment: if you have more questions post them here, i'll try to answer