# i can't find any thing on my telegram bot API

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to get all the `chat_id`'s in the telegram bot API

When I call

https://api.telegram.org/botmybot_token/getUpdates

I get this `{"ok":true,"result":[]}`

Answer (score 4):

You get empty updates because there were no messages (or other actions) from users.

To obtain user's `chat_id` follow these steps:

1. User must **first** find the bot and send it any message, [because](https://core.telegram.org/bots#4-how-are-bots-different-from-humans)

   > Bots can't initiate conversations with users. A user must either add them to a group or send them a message first. People can use telegram.me/ links or username search to find your bot.
2. Get the following URL: https://api.telegram.org/botmybot_token/getUpdates?timeout=300. Note that [you should use](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates) `timeout=` because this is a [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) method (i.e. you will receive response only when there is a new incoming update or timeout is reached):

   > (timeout is) Timeout in seconds for long polling. **Defaults to 0**, i.e. usual short polling. Should be positive, short polling should be used **for testing purposes only**.

You can still receive updates without `timeout` setting, but that's not the right way to read user interaction. Instead you can you just run long-polling (i.e. with `timeout` setting) requests in a loop.

You can read more on getting infromation about user's `chat_id` here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56093268/2315573